# Removing all grid's children in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, grid, children

I'm trying to remove all children (and sub-children) of a `Grid` in WPF (I'm really new to the whole WPF business). Is there a good way of doing it programmatically? I need to do this so that I could leave an empty canvas (`Grid`) at one point and draw other stuff on it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

hmmm

```
myGrid.Children.Clear();
```

?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. = ) I was looking for a method of `Grid`, not `Grid.Children`

Comment: he he he... often, the most obvious things are invisible even to the trained eye ;)